# What happens to the energy in an ocean wave after it breaks on a reef or the shore?

Tags: waves, energy-conservation, everyday-life, dissipation, oceanography

I understand that the conservation of energy essentially says that "energy can neither be destroyed or created but that it is transferred from one form to another." Given that, on the ocean, wind energy gets transferred to the sea where it then takes the form of a wave. Ocean waves travel sometimes a thousand kilometers or more. When a wave reaches the shore or a reef it breaks. My question is where does that ocean wave energy go after it breaks, I know it creates sound which is sound energy but that does not seem like enough. Where does the energy go when the sound dies out? Where does the energy go?

Comment: The answer to basically any "where does the energy go?" question is : "heat". You just need to wait long enough. And in that case, you don't need to wait for long.

Comment: Consider that when you drive your 2 ton car 80mph (speak for myself) and slow down to a stop, almost all of that energy has been converted to heat in your break pads! Heat can store a lot more energy than you might think.

Comment: *Especially*  when water is involved. It takes a massive amount of heat to warm up large amounts of water.

Comment: One thing that is consistent with all of this that I have learned is that energy seems to either love to be stored in the form of a solid or exist in the form of a wave, or in the form of wind energy, but that's close to a wave as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This is an interesting article](https://manoa.hawaii.edu/exploringourfluidearth/physical/waves/wave-energy-and-wave-changes-depth) with some numbers for the energy in waves

[image: waves]

> A wave with a height of 2 m and a wavelength of 14 m breaking along 2 km of coastline (surface area = 32,000 m<sup>2</sup>) has approximately 45 kWh of energy.

How it will be dissipated will depend on the approach to the coast.

A wave as seen above will start losing energy by transferring it to kinetic and rotational energy at the shallow bottom including sand transfers, which finally will become heat (extra kinetic energy). As there will be conservation of momentum also, part of it will be absorbed by the impact on the earth, as vibrations which will also end up as heat, and also any dissipation in air as you observe. In the picture above sand will be continually deposited on the shore changing the shore line.

A wave hitting a rocky precipice will be transferring vibrations (finally heat) but also will [erode part of the rock.](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/101587379#)

In the end all energy will end up as a higher temperature in the region and ground than if the ocean were calm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the amount of heat that is created by the breaking wave is so imperceptibly small that I never could have imagined that that was what was happening, but it does make perfect sense. the energy goes from wind to water to sound and heat. Now I need to find out where the energy comes from before it is wind energy. Rotation of the earth perhaps?

Comment: The sun  heats the atmosphere land and ocean  unevenly ( night day, summer ,winter)which generates atmospheric circulation (storms and winds). The energy comes from the sun ( well maybe some active volcanos and internal earth heat will change temperatures also and affect the winds and storms). The rotation affects the wind circulation and the weather systems but sun is the main energy source

Comment: So when I ride a wave I am essentially riding energy that originated in the sun, or when I hear a breaking wave I am hearing the last breath of the energy that came from the sun. Incredible. The energy starts with nuclear fusion in the sun right?

Comment: @Brando Yes.  If you want to trace it all the way back in that way, you are solar surfing!    Or, if you feel like taking it a bit further, you're surfing on echos of the big bang.  Totally tubular, man!

Comment: Cort Ammon, "Echos of the Big Bang," totally got it, the atoms that are doing the fusion in the suns core originated in the big bang or in another supernova event, essentially when I ride a wave I'm riding energy that originated during the big bang, it has just transferred many times before it became the wave that I am riding. Totally deep bro, and completely fascinating.

Comment: @Brando: Almost all energy on earth comes from the sun. There are some exceptions: nuclear energy (yes, there are such things as natural nuclear reactors) and geothermal. Everything else is from the sun. For example, petrol comes from ancient organic matter which at some point come from ancient plants which gets energy from the sun. Now think about firewood: photons from the sun inject enough energy for plants to make sugar which gets converted to cellulose which becomes wood. Every time you burn wood you're releasing light from the sun.

Comment: slebetman, that's amazing to, think about it, when your burning wood your releasing energy from the sun. Where does the energy go from there though. Heat energy and light energy never to be used by man again most likely, but remaining still, just in a different form?

Comment: the earth is also continuously radiating black body radiation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation  keeping the temperature balanced  in thermodynamic equilibrium, what comes in from the sun goes eventually out since  does not t burn up but has on average a specific temperature.

Comment: Anna, I will never get past only a rudimentary understanding of concepts such as "black body radiation" because I do not understand the math. I have attempted to remedy my problem by enrolling in math courses at my local community college but because I am forty years old my wife just thinks that I want to go back to college to troll for younger women. Oh well, maybe in the next life I will get a deeper understanding of our physical world, but for now, I get only glimpses and can marvel LOL

Answer (score 6):

When a wave breaks on the shore, most of the kinetic energy that was propagated in the wave goes into vigorously stirring up the water and mixing it with air as it runs up and then down the beach slope. In so doing it also shoves sand and pebbles around as pointed out by JMLCarter. The stirring action dissipates energy via the viscosity of the water, which warms up by a tiny amount, and that heat is then shared with the sand and air nearby.

Answer (score -1):

Costal errosion. Movement of sand and stones etc.

Comment: This is inadequate as an answer. You might consider deleting it.